# text alignment between tabular and multicolumn environments

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am currently trying to work on a latex table to report data on different categories and have countered text alignment issues. I have tried to use two multicolumn environments and combination of multrow and multicolumn with no success.

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{demo}
    \label{tbl:demo}
    \begin{tabular}{ ccccc }
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{name} &
            \begin{tabular}{c}
                    Category1 \\
                    column1 \\
            \end{tabular}
            &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Category2}\\ %\cline{3-4}
            && column1 &column2  \\
            \hline
            n1 & 1 &  7 & 5 \\
            n2  &- & 6 & 4 \\
            n3 & 2 & 9 & 3 \\
            \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table with incorrect heading alignment]

Any pointers on how I can fix the alignment of the headers?

Kenneth

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version with `booktabs` and correct alignment.

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{demo}
    \label{tbl:demo}
    \begin{tabular}{ ccccc }
            \toprule
             & Category1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Category 2}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
            name & column1 & column1 &column2 \\
            \midrule
            n1 & 1 &  7 & 5 \\
            n2  &- & 6 & 4 \\
            n3 & 2 & 9 & 3 \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```